# How to get a Parser from a DescriptorProto of a message type?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

After creating it in the first #region, the following code converts a wire format binary of a message into a json string in the second #region with [Google.Protobuf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Protobuf/) library

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    #region create example object and write it to a file in binary wire format

    var john = new Person // defined in Addressbook.cs protoc-compiled from addressbook.proto
    {
        Id = 1234,
        Name = "John Doe",
        Email = "jdoe@example.com",
        Phones = { new PhoneNumber { Number = "555-4321", Type = PhoneType.Home } }
    };

    var binaryFileName = "john";
    using (var output = File.Create(binaryFileName))
    {
        john.WriteTo(output);
    }

    #endregion

    #region convert wire format binary to json

    using (var input = File.OpenRead(binaryFileName))
    {
        var message = Person.Descriptor.Parser.ParseFrom(input);
        var json = new JsonFormatter(JsonFormatter.Settings.Default).Format(message);

        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I'd like to recreate this functionality with the [protobuf-net](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net) library obtaining the `Descriptor` via Reflection from the .proto file, not the source code compiled from that .proto file.

I got as far as having the descriptor for the message. **How can I get a [`MessageParser`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/message-parser#class_google_1_1_protobuf_1_1_message_parser) equivalent from the `DescriptorProto`?**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var binaryFileName = "john";

    var set = new FileDescriptorSet();
    set.Add("addressbook.proto", true, new StreamReader("addressbook.proto"));
    set.Process();
    
    var errors = set.GetErrors();
    foreach (var error in errors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(error);
    }
    
    foreach (var file in set.Files)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file.Name);

        foreach (var messageType in file.MessageTypes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(messageType.Name);
        }
    }
    
    var personType = set.Files.SelectMany(file => file.MessageTypes).FirstOrDefault(messageType => messageType.Name == "Person");

    // personType.Parser. ???

}
```

---

## clarification/comments

> I think what you're asking is: given a schema known only at runtime via a parsed .proto, how can we deserialize the data - presumably into some runtime-only model (we should not assume that we have access to any generated/matching types).

Eventually, I want to convert between wire binary format to human readable text, see [How to convert a binary message to a human readable format (e.g. json) given its .proto file at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62553336/11398730)

**I do not necessarily need to have any model to deserialize into and from which serialization/formatting to readable text would happen, if there's any other way of doing that sort of format conversion.** This is merely the workflow that seems to be the most likely one to actually work, at least from what I found on the net.

The problem is that the runtime capabilities necessary for this sort of reflection based handling of ProtoBuffers is different across languages (and even libraries in one language as you point out). Uglyness of possible solutions is hard to estimate, as it always comes from very detailed aspects, e.g. requiring a compiled schema, requiring invocation of protoc, not being able to get the parser from `DescriptorProto`, not having certain functionality available in C#, etc.

That's why I'm trying to implement different solutions, like the one in this question, to see if that particular road is blocked and if so whether by a wall or a mountain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're asking is: given a schema known only at runtime via a parsed .proto, how can we deserialize the data - presumably into some runtime-only model (we should not assume that we have access to any generated/matching types).

If that is correct, then that is functionality that is not currently implemented in protobuf-net. You *could* read the data as a `Extensible` subclass, and then manually access the fields via the extensions API, but that would be hard, slow and ugly. Another option might be to generate the matching model in C# at runtime, compile it, and run it - but that is again: complex and not necessarily particularly fast (unless you can cache the types etc). There is also a reader API, if you wanted to walk through a protobuf stream field-by-field, and for each: compare against the schema that you're holding, and do ... something with the values.

Ultimately, I have not yet done the discovery work to imagine what a *usable and useful* API for this scenario would be, let alone implement it. I'm open to suggestions, but probably on GitHub issues.

Comment: I do not need the intermediate steps, but I found no way around them so far. Please see my clarifying edit to the question for more info.

Comment: @user11398730 so your main aim is to convert it to JSON? yeah, that's not going to be trivial; protobuf-net does not implement the JSON APIs, and I haven't planned to add support for that. Using most mainstream JSON serializers is going to need an object model, and note that even then: that won't be the very opinionated JSON that the Google protobuf JSON layer writes. There's no magic "here's the 7 lines of code" to do what you want. My suggestion for the simplest option would be: use the code-gen API in protobuf-net.Reflection to get C#, and compile that to types; deserialize, serialize JSON.